# How can I retrieve the user pass for fishpig magento wordpress integration?

Tags: wordpress, fishpig, magento-1.9

I have just taken this site over and it already has the fishpig plugin installed. The site was upgraded to 1.9 but not yet the fishpig. I can not log in with my magento credentials, I cant manage the users because of an autologin error. How can I gain access and reset the auto-login?

This is [installed](http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~scofi0/index.php/blog/) on a dev server for now:
Thank you!

Comment: I might be totally wrong here (I'd be interested to find out I am) but that Autologin feature stopped working ages ago when Wordpress was upgraded - from memory I think it was around 3.6. I just ignore it and login to Wordpress directly, its just a little feature that it probably isn't worth maintaining and upgrading for.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to see whether or not you can login to the WordPress Admin directly as 95% of auto-login problems are caused by WP not being correctly setup.

If you cannot login to the WordPress Admin, either use the 'Forgot Password?' link or reset the [password directly in the database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin). If the WordPress Admin is inaccessible, you will need to correctly set the 'siteurl' option in the database using phpMyAdmin and then try logging in again.

Once you are able to login to the WordPress Admin, enter the details in the configuration for the [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) extension and try logging in. If this doesn't work, upgrade the extension to the latest version.

Comment: Interesting to see your post Ben.  Am I right in saying what I've said in my comment for the OP?  I remember the auto login working well and then at some point it stopped working on a load of sites at the same time, so I assumed that a Wordpress upgrade had prevented that feature from working?

Comment: Yes, a certain WP update did break the auto-login (I forget which update) but this was fixed within a week. This could be this users problem as he's using an old version of the extension so upgrading would definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

user passwords are usually md5 protected. if you want to actually get passwords
altho not suggested and safe.. you keep a text version inside your database.